# TypeError when parsing a nested Json in python

Tags: python, json, parsing

I am trying to parse a json but i am running into an error. Using this json as an example:

```
  "creator": "Deliveries",
  "sales": [
    {
      "sale_id": 123,
      "sale_date": "2021-01-01",
      "pickup_from": {
        "location_id": 321,
        "city": "Washington",
        "state": "VA"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and trying to print `sale_id` and `sale_date` and amount from `sales` and `location_id` and `city` from `pickup_from` using the code:

```
for sale in file_json['sales']:
        
    for store in sale['pickup_from']:
        print(sale['sale_id'])
        print(sale['sale_date'])
        print(store['location_id'])
        print(store['city'])
```

looking to the output:

```
123
2021-01-01
321
Washington
```

I am getting type error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-5dda8493c9d7> in <module>
     46         print(sale['sale_id'])
     47         print(sale['sale_date'])
---> 48         print(store['location_id'])
     49         print(store['city'])

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I know Im parsing it incorrectly, but not sure where Im going wrong.

Comment: did you at least `print(store)` to see the problem ?

Comment: I did.. looks like I needed to add an additional key and there is no need to loop over twice:

```for sale in file_json['sales']:
    print(sale['sale_id'])
    print(sale['sale_date'])
    print(sale['pickup_from']['location_id'])
    print(sale['pickup_from']['city'])
```